# How to call Geth methods via RPC from Javascript?

Tags: go-ethereum, rpc

I would like to access the debug namespace (https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/ns-debug) from my Javascript code (I'm using my own node, not a 3rd party provider). How can I do something like this? I've gone as far as to configure the node with `--http` and calling the methods from the Geth console. Now I just need to access the API from my code. Thanks.

Comment: Just make an api call to the rpc endpoint from your js call. This is more node js than blockchain stuff

Comment: Or use ethers or web3js to do this